# Database connection failed:dial tcp <host>:<port>: connectex: A connection attempt failed

Tags: mysql, go, google-cloud-platform, terraform, connection-string

First post, will try to make this as descriptive as possible.

I started a side-project using Terraform, GCP, and mySQL. I'm completely new to these technologies, so I apologize in advance for any ignorance. I am getting an error when trying to connect to the SQL database via my Go app.

I'm using Terraform to stand up a "google_sql_database_instance":

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance" {
  name             = "name"
  database_version = "MYSQL_8_0"
  project          = "project_id"
  region           = "us-central1"

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro" # Choose an appropriate machine type
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  name     = var.db_DSN
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance.name
}

resource "google_sql_user" "database_user" {
  name     = var.db_name
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance.name
  password = var.db_password
}
```

Terraform stands up the instance with no problems.

My issue comes from trying to connect to the SQL database via Golang. In my main.go file I'm trying to connect like this:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    host := <public_ip_address> // Public IP Address from the SQL instance on GCP       
    port := 3306       // MySQL default port
    user := "test"       
    password := "test123"   
    dbname := <db_name>    
    sslmode := "disable"              

    // Construct the connection string
    connStr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s", user, password, host, port, dbname)

    fmt.Println(connStr)

    // Open a database connection
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Test the connection
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Database connection failed:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected to the database!")
}
```

and after running `go run cmd/main.go`, I am met with this error:

`Database connection failed:dial tcp <host>:3306: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`.

I have the firewall rules set up to allow a connection via tcp:3306, all of my conenction details are quadruple checked and correct, and my ip ranges are set as such:

IP ranges       0.0.0.0/0 (My understanding is this allows a connection via my local machine, correct me if I'm wrong please)

and I'm lost on where to go from here. Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

- I've tried using postgresql as well, which means I may be missing a very valuable piece, but cannot figure out what it is.
- I've tried standing up new instances with new users and connections.
- Of course I tried ChatGPT.
- Very strong possibility I'm missing a key fundamental detail (probably in GCP), but cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: What kind of firewall rule did you create? The term used for Cloud SQL is `whitelisting`. Did you whitelist the VM's IP address in Cloud SQL or did you create a VPC Firewall rule for the VM? You are connecting from the VM to Cloud SQL. Therefore, you must allow the VM's address to connect to Cloud SQL by configuring that IP address in Cloud SQL.

Comment: For Compute Engine, I recommend that you configure and use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy instead of whitelisting IP addresses. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy